# nuget package run on local not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, razorengine, rotativa

[i want to generate pdf from Razor view ,i used Rotativa nuget package or HiqPDF package ,it working fine on local machine but when i hosted on server it will give following error,help me to resolve an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQwkj.jpg)

Server Error in '/' Application.

Error 0x4EC. Check the HiQPdf.dep resource file can be found near the HiQPdf.dll assembly and the user has read and execute permissions for this file. Call SetDepFilePath() method if you placed the HiQPdf.dep in a different location

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details:
>
> System.Exception: Error 0x4EC. Check the HiQPdf.dep resource file can
>   be found near the HiQPdf.dll assembly and the user has read and
>   execute permissions for this file. Call SetDepFilePath() method if you
>   placed the HiQPdf.dep in a different location

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the program is blocked by a group policy of the server. If you have a shared server you might want to try on a dedicated server which is not affected by shared hosting provider restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Rotativa doesn't work because the server your app is hosted on doesn't let running external processes.
You either switch to a server/hosting/cloud solution that enables it or you can try the online service (SaaS) http://RotativaHQ.com